# Many TCP connections at CLOSE_WAIT state on Google Analytics IP address

Tags: asp.net, tcp, google-analytics

I have added `Google Analytics` script to my website (ASP.NET on Windows server 2008 R2) pages. I was monitoring TCP connections on the server and accidentally find out that there are hundreds of TCP connections at `CLOSE_WAIT` state. I checked the remote address and the reomte port was 80 (http). There was a blank screen and the view source shows you `Google analytics` javascript code.

What's wrong here? Why there are hundreds of TCP connections frozen at `CLOSE_WAIT` at those addresses with `Google Analytic` code?

Comment: I'm curious... do you have any software firewalls running on this machine?  What virus scanner are you using?

Comment: @Mike: Nothing. A pure windows with the built-in firewall. I checked again and it's OK for now ! Maybe a transient failure in Google service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CLOSE_WAIT` is the TCP state when the remote side has closed the connection but the local application has not.  Google's service has done it's work but your browser/whatever is not doing its part.  This could be a problem with the application or the Javascript it's executing.

Given that you have hundreds, they've probably accumulated over viewing many web pages.  Restarting the browser should clear them.  If they keep accumulating, see if it is only that particular browser and report a bug (to either Google or the browser author, or both).

Comment: I did not encounter the situation any more.